# Use JWT to access JIRA API using Python JIRA

Tags: python, jira, jwt, jira-rest-api, python-jira

Python JIRA currently don't have documentation on how to use it. I've looked on the source code and found credentials that are needed but I don't know where or how to get it (eg. shared secret, payload).

```
      :param jwt: A dict of properties for JWT authentication supported by Atlassian Connect. The following
        properties are required:
        * secret -- shared secret as delivered during 'installed' lifecycle event
        (see https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/modules/lifecycle.html for details)
        * payload -- dict of fields to be inserted in the JWT payload, e.g. 'iss'
        Example jwt structure: ``{'secret': SHARED_SECRET, 'payload': {'iss': PLUGIN_KEY}}``
```

I have looked on JIRA but the docs always mention about using JWT to add-ons.

What I understand in JWT is that I will use my username and password, then submit it to a particular link to receive a token, then use the token. And I am lost in [JIRA Docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/concepts/understanding-jwt.html) because its too complicated and not what I've expected.

Comment: Did you get it working? python-jira do not have any example how to use JWT.

Comment: I was not able to figure it out. I used token base instead.

Comment: I got this working with JWT, but I had to change some code in the library to get it working because the header created by the library was not correct. It was now corrected in the library (on [GitHub](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/pull/493) ) but still has not been released.

Comment: The latest release should have fixed the issue [commented here](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/pull/493)